# Where to look for this grammar style? She grew up "listening" to that song

Tags: grammar

When we say "She grew up **listening** to that song" instead of "She grew up **while she was listening** to that song", which grammar rule are we applying?

Answer (score 1):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [while](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/while#h2):

> conjunction
>
> **1a** : during the time that
>   // take a nap while I'm out

---

> She grew up **while** she was listening to that song.

This means that when the song started she was not grown up, but by the time the song stopped she *was* grown up. Which would mean that show grew up in the span of approximately five minutes. (Or however long it took the song to play.)

We can reverse the elements in the *while* sentence:

> She listened to that song **while** she was growing up.

Now, the song listening occurred during the many years it took her to grow up.

---

Whether or not your two sentences means the same thing comes down to the meaning of *grew up*.

1. If *grew up* is being used *figuratively*, then these two sentences mean the same thing:

   > She grew up **while** she was listening to that song.
   >   She grew up **listening** to that song.

   In both cases, hearing the particular song was a defining moment in her maturity. Hearing it caused her some kind of life-altering insight, and she "grew up" as the song was being played.

---

2. If *grew up* is being used *literally*, then these two sentences mean the same thing:

   > She listened to that song **while** she was growing up.
   >   She grew up **listening** to that song.

   In both cases, she listened to the song during the span of time when she physically changed from a child to an adult.

Comment: I don't agree that to say someone "grew up listening" to a song always means that hearing the song was a "defining moment. It could just mean that the song was often heard (e.g. on the radio) while the person passed from childhood to adulthood. In fact, that is the meaning I would normally presume. I grew up listening to barbershop records because my dad played them a lot, but it hardly "defined" me, except as a person who hates barbershop.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I didn't say that's what it always meant. I said that could be a figurative interpretation. I provided  a literal interpretation as well.

Comment: @JasonBassford Sometimes we know that we do not know something, we ask and learn it. Sometimes we even do not know that we do not know something. Your reply was the latter to me and I learned how differently it could be interpreted. But still I am interested to read from a grammar source about situations that we remove "while she was" and only keep the "listening". Where should I look for such examples?